# Given 2 lists with the same values but different ordering, how close are they to each other?

Tags: correlation, agreement-statistics, euclidean

I've implemented an application that collects some relevant data about certain topics, so for each topic I get a list of strings. I want to make a test to see if the data makes sense.

I thought of making a survey, given the same list items (unsorted) and ask the survey takers to sort them. Then I would see how close the ordering of the human-sorted results to mine. Is this a good idea? would you recommend another method?

To do this I thought of using distance metrics such as [Euclidean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), [Manhattan (city block)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_block), and [Chessboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance). But I will be comparing how relevant the survey's results are to my application's results, can I argue that my results are okay if these values are low? I feel it should be done the other way around.. it is as if I am using my own results as my ground truth

Comment: Hi there, I'm not clear on what the application is doing. You say it is getting a list of strings, but then you later talk about sorting. I'm not seeing the link between your first paragraph - data collection - and your second paragraph - data sorting. Can you add more detail?

Comment: Well, it gets a list of strings sorted by relevance, I want to argue that my list is really sorted by relevance. So I thought changing the order of the list and asking people to sort them by relevance. Then I can see how close my list is to their's.

Comment: You'll need to ensure that the same definition of "relevance" is used by you and the raters. This will require rater training.